# Enable Directline in MS BOT Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, direct-line-botframework

1) I created a REST API for my client application and Registered in API Management (that used to get user specific data)

2) I created a BOT WEB APP in Azure portal using LUIS and it is working fine (I added sample Intents/Utterance)

3) Consumed the REST API in LUIS application as one of the Intent condition 
Tested the above in BOT Emulator and Azure portal as well. (Hard-coded the user info in the calling function)

Now I want to configure the BOT in my MVC client application and pass the user specific info based on the logged in user info. I read the below article to enable the directline API. Still looking for the better resources.

[Connect BOT using Directline API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-channel-connect-directline#add-new-site)

[DirectLine Auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication)

Comment: Honestly your question is too broad to get a clear answer. What do you want to do here? What is the use case of the bot in your MVC client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I want to configure the BOT in my MVC client application and pass the user specific info based on the logged in user info.

I’m using the following code sample to embed bot in my website and pass user specific information to bot, which works for me, you can refer to it.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <div id="mybot"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    BotChat.App({
        directLine: { secret: '{your_directline_secret}' },
        //you can dynamically retrieve the logged in user info in your mvc View
        //and pass thoes info to your bot
        user: { id: '1234', firstname: '{your_fname}', lastname: '{your_lname}'},
        bot: { id: '{your_botid}' },
        resize: 'detect'
    }, document.getElementById("mybot"))
</script>
```

**Test result:**

[image]

Using the following code snippet to extract user information from `Activity` object in bot app.

```
if (activity.From.Properties["firstname"] != null)
{
    var fname = activity.From.Properties["firstname"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically you problem is about implementing a bot interface inside a web app. One option could be to use WebChat as a channel: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat.

The open source web chat control communicates with your bot by using the Direct Line API, which allows messages to be sent back and forth between client and bot. You can embed it in your web app by just adding the `<iframe>` tag as mentioned in the docs. Check more info here as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-design-pattern-embed-web-site

Otherwise as you said is to use Direct Line API and implement a networking layer to this API in your MVC client APP. This would be in charge of building the messages and sending it to the bot API, and receiving them and using it to the corresponding UI needs. Personally I recommend you to use WebSockets protocol in order to establish a two way communication between your bot and avoid doing HTTP long polling. Check it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts

Comment: Thank you!. I have analysed all of these options but confused with which approach to choose. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-design-pattern-embed-web-site seems to be good with Styles and all but i am not confident if i can customize the responses from my c# code and not sure if i can extend other channels easily (Alexa and CORTANA etc)